# How to stack multiple numpy 2d arrays into one 3d array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Here's my code:

```
img = imread("lena.jpg")
for channel in range(3):
    res = filter(img[:,:,channel], filter)
    # todo: stack to 3d here
```

As you can see, I'm applying some filter for every channel in the picture. How do I stack them back to a 3d array? (= the original image shape)

Thanks

Comment: Collect the `res` in a list.  `np.stack(alist, axis=2)` can be used to join them into an array on a last `channel` axis.

Comment: You have `filter` both as a function and variable, beware of that. Also what kind of filter are you using? I don't see your filter variable is changing by the channel, so why not do a 3D filter and avoid the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [np.dstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
import numpy as np

image = np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 100, 3))

r, g, b = image[:, :, 0], image[:, :, 1], image[:, :, 2]

result = np.dstack((r, g, b))

print("image shape", image.shape)
print("result shape", result.shape)
```

**Output**

```
image shape (100, 100, 3)
result shape (100, 100, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd initialize a variable with the needed shape before:

```
img = imread("lena.jpg")
res = np.zeros_like(img)     # or simply np.copy(img)
for channel in range(3):
    res[:, :, channel] = filter(img[:,:,channel], filter)
```